# How to show category siblings?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalog, category

I have a Magento based website.
In my product page I need to show related categories regarding the category the product fall into.

For example suppose the category structure 
A- has three child categories B,C and D. Where C has a product than on this product page i need to show B and D as a related category.

Is there is any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the tag ecomdev-phpunit by purpose? Are you trying to do this during an unit test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that you already have the current category in the variable $category.
This piece of code should give you all the (active) category siblings.

```
$siblings = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$siblings->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getParentId()) //siblings have the same parent as the current category
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq'=>$category->getId()))//exclude current category
        ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position
```

Now you can loop through the siblings and list them:

```
<?php foreach ($siblings as $sibling): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $sibling->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $sibling->getName();?></a><br />
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks Marius your code works like a charm, thanks for the great help.